# Struct declaration and pointer in one line

Tags: c, pointers, struct, declaration

I search for a way to initialize a struct and return this struct pointer in one line. (Portable way is the best, but for gcc at least)

For example, I got a function :

```
void myfunc(const mystruct_t *ptr);
```

A structure definition :

```
typedef struct mystruct_t{
    int field1;
    const char *field2;
}mystruct_t;
```

I can do :

```
const mystruct_t mystruct={.field1=23, .field2="myname" };
myfunc(&mystruct);
```

I there a way to do this in one line ?

something like :

```
myfunc(&{.field1=23, .field2="myname" });
```

Comment: I think the dot-named-initialization syntax you're using is a GCC extension anyway (since you mentioned portability).

Comment: If you want they are in one line, just put they in same line. If you mean you want to use same ";", I believe that there is no way because you need to declare an object before get it's address.

Comment: @szczurcio: Please update to the 16 year old previous version of the C standard. Designated intialisers are standard since C99.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), supported since C99.

```
myfunc(&(mystruct_t){.field1=23, .field2="myname" });
```

Comment: Simple and obvious solution, yet I had tried without success, but I just try again and confirm that it works. Many thanks all

Comment: With OP's original `const mystruct_t mystruct={.field1=23, .field2="myname" }; myfunc(&mystruct);` , the `mystruct` lifetime lasts until the block it is declared in closes.  Does this compound literal last the same?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals) (*A gcc extension before `C99`, which is supported by the standard since `C99`*), something like

```
myfunc(&(mystruct_t){23, "myname"});
```

should be possible.

Comment: Compound literals are not a gcc extension anymore since >16 years. They are standard since C99.

Comment: @Olaf Right, but we don't know the OP's environment, do we? :)

Comment: 5That is not a matter of the environment, but the language implementation provided by the compiler. As always, without some ancient compiler, we have to assume standard C, which is C11 in general, but as there were no relevant changes in this area, C99 would be also acceptable. If OP uses gcc already, he also can use C11 (or C99) mode, which might be the lesser "problem" than using extensions. (It also is much more portable.)

Comment: @Olaf I was under the impression that the compiler (support) is also considered as the _environment_. However, added a note to clarify. :)

Comment: The C standard clearly differentiates betwee the terms "environment" and "implementation". It sometimes is not that simple to seperate them (e.g. when it comes to the signature of `main`). But now I understand you mean the development platform. But anyway, if you use gcc anyway, why prefer that extension to directly being standard-compliant? Note that OP already uses _designated intialisers_, so he apparently already uses C99 features.

Comment: @Olaf Right. Modified the wordings. :)

Comment: Still not happy with the text (why so much emphasis on gcc?), but I removed the DV. Maybe it's just full moon madness ;-) or lack of sunshine here.

Comment: "Designated initializers" to be supported in C++20. Should make everyone who is porting C to C++ very happy.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you could do this through a constructor but with C99 compound literal is what you need.

NOTE: I know it is tagged as C. It is just another alternative I want to give.